# React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child error while using Ref

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have to call some methods from component B inside component A. 
Here is the component B: (In the case that you need more code just request me and I will update my post)

```
import A  from "./A";
export default class B extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    this.props.onRef(this);
  }

  renderContent ( ) {
    let toolbarActiveItem = Toolbar.getActiveItem();
    if (Toolbar.getActiveItem()=="XXXX") {
      this.refs.A._showModalHistory();
    } else {
      toolbarActiveItem = Toolbar.getActiveItem();
    }

    return (
      <Container>
        {(toolbarActiveItem == 'YYY') && <C navigation={this.props.navigation} cb={this.childCallback} info={this.props.navigation.state.params}/> }
      </Container>
    );
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <StyleProvider style={getTheme(Config.theme)}>
        <A ref={component => { this.A = component; }} />
        <Container ref={this.ref}>
          { this.renderNavbar(this.title) }
          { this.renderToolbar() }
          { this.renderContent() }
          { this.renderDialog() }
        </Container>
      </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
```

Here is the component A:

```
export default class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.subscription = 0;
    this.state = {};
    changePage = props.cb;

    this.state = {
      isModalVisibleHistory: false,
    };
  }

  _showModalHistory = () => this.setState({ isModalVisibleHistory: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisibleHistory}>
        <View style={styles.BG}>
        <ParkHistory></ParkHistory>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is that, I need to execute `this.refs.A._showModalHistory();` in component B but, I see the following error:

> React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

I think, I have a problem to deal with rendering multiple components and ref them. I should mention that, when I delete `<A ref={component => { this.A = component; }} />` my code works fine but, without calling the method. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are accessing the ref. You have assigned ref to `Component A`. You are using the callback style to assign ref and so you need not write `this.ref.A`. Change it to `this.A._showModalHistory();`

Aslo the way you are setting ref to Container component is incorrect, you need to use callback there

```
<Container ref={(ref)=> this.ref = ref}>
```

One other thing is that the StyleProvider component expects a single child element. You should wrap your `Container` and `A` component in `View`

```
render () {
    return (
      <StyleProvider style={getTheme(Config.theme)}>
        <View>
        <A ref={component => { this.A = component; }} />
        <Container ref={(ref)=> this.ref = ref}>
          { this.renderNavbar(this.title) }
          { this.renderToolbar() }
          { this.renderContent() }
          { this.renderDialog() }
        </Container>
        </View>
      </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it again shows me the same error. :(

Comment: Thanks, It shows me a new error. Which is "Undefined is not an object (evaluating props.info)". I think it doesn't let the render() to access the mentioned props while it wrapped in a <View>.

Comment: Are you using the `info` prop passed to component C anywhere. Maybe thats where this problem arises from

Comment: Yes, I pass it to component C but, I can not avoid passing info there. You can see it in the code, here: "{(toolbarActiveItem == 'YYY') && <C navigation={this.props.navigation} cb={this.childCallback} info={this.props.navigation.state.params}/> }". Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you know any other approach so that, I can call my method instead of using ref?

Comment: Can you post the code for component `C`. Are you using `use strict` somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158954/discussion-between-queen-and-shubham-khatri).